# How to capture voice of user using Avaya IVR?

Tags: voice-recognition, ivr, voicexml, avaya

Dears,

I want to capture voice of users using IVR built on Orchestration Designer and store it in file system as wav files. As far as I know, there is a way to do that by using Speech Servers such as Nuance,but, since it is expensive we want to find an alternative way. I have been searching internet for week, but could not find anything related. Is there a way to capture voice using java or voiceXML? Is it even possible without using speech servers?

Comment: Look for keywords like: IVR Recording, Trunk Recording, Voicemail or <record>. Can it be done: sure. Can it be done with this product: no idea. Most companies that sell IVR's will either have recording solutions build in or sell it as a separate service/product. But I'm not familiar enough with their specific product line to comment.

Answer (score 0):

you could use recoding node to record the voice. '.wav' would be saved in data/temp in your application but it would be deleted once your session is over. You need to write customize java code to copy and paste from temp to your local dir before the session gets invalidated.

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question. Adding a code example would be great.

Comment: @JeroenHeier you can mail on sha02shi2gmail.com, I will share with you simple example.